# Largest substring matching across two different data frames

Tags: regex, r

I have two different data.frames "String" and "Keywords" with single columns as mentioned below. "String" has 50000 rows and "Keywords", 10000 rows.

```
String
#I love New York  
#Live in Los Angeles  
#He stays in Yorkshire  
#Condo in Lowell  
# ...

Keywords 
#Ohio  
#Montreal  
#Los Vego  
#York  
#New York   
#Lowell    
#...
```

The result should be stored in a dataframe with columns "String" and "Result" which looks as shown below

```
Result  

#              String        Result  
#       I love New York    New York     
#   Live in Los Angeles          NA  
# He stays in Yorkshire        York  
#       Condo in Lowell      Lowell
```

The string matching should be exact but can be case insensitive.

Comment: What happens when 2 equal sized large strings match to `String`? e.g.: `I love New York` would match `New York` and `love New`.

Comment: It still doesn't perform the exact match of the term in the dataframe **Keyword**. For eg. Keyword York should't be returned for string He stays in Yorkshire. (If Keyword Yorkshire is present, it should only return Yorkshire). Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be much quicker than the nested loops shown so far. On my machine, without any parallelisation, it completes on 100,000 strings and 50,000 words/substrings in about 12.5 minutes.

Sample data:

```
library("data.table")
# Downloaded from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/airport-codes/master/data/airport-codes.csv
airports <- fread("airport-codes.csv")
first_bit <- paste(c("Lives", "Works", "Plays", "Condo", "Apartment", "I love"), "in")

places <- unique(c(airports$name, airports[!municipality == "", municipality]))

set.seed(123)
strings <- data.table(
  string = paste(sample(first_bit, 1e5, TRUE),
                 sample(places, 1e5, TRUE))
)
words <- sample(places, 5e4)
```

Actual routine based on `grepl`:

```
system.time({
  strings[, `:=`(lower = tolower(string), result = NA_character_)]
  words <- words[order(nchar(words), words, decreasing = TRUE)]
  i <- 0
  for (x in words) {
    i <- i + 1
    if (i %% 100 == 0) cat(i, "\n")
    found <- grepl(tolower(x), strings$lower, fixed = TRUE)
    strings[found & is.na(result), result := x]
  }
  strings[, lower := NULL]
})
```

Note on Windows, `fread` and its ilk work on https links out of the box, but on linux you'd need to use `download.file` and the appropriate `curl` or `wget` option.

**Edit** The OP now indicates that he only wants whole word matching. This could be achieved using non-fixed matching and the `\b` syntax in regex. However, it's also an opportunity to do the whole thing much quicker.

Here is a suggested algorithm that takes less than a minute to run on my machine. It splits each string into words at space boundaries (after first condensing multiple consecutive spaces into one). It then calculates the length of every possible substring made of whole words. The sought keywords are then split by length and `match` can be used to look for exact matches between the substrings and keywords. Because the keywords are sorted largest to smallest, it will always use the longest keyword available.

```
library("data.table")
library("stringr")
# Downloaded from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/airport-codes/master/data/airport-codes.csv
airports <- fread("airport-codes.csv")
first_bit <- paste(c("Lives", "Works", "Plays", "Condo", "Apartment", "I love"), "in")

places <- unique(c(airports$name, airports[!municipality == "", municipality]))

set.seed(123)
strings <- data.table(
  string = paste(sample(first_bit, 1e5, TRUE),
                 sample(places, 1e5, TRUE))
)
words <- sample(places, 5e4)

system.time({
  strings[, `:=`(lower = tolower(str_replace_all(string, "\\s+", " ")), result = NA_character_, str_no = .I)]
  setkey(strings, str_no)
  words_dt <- data.table(word = words[order(nchar(words), words, decreasing = TRUE)])
  words_dt[, lower := tolower(str_replace_all(word, "\\s+", " "))]
  words_dt[, nc := nchar(lower)]

  gaps <- str_locate_all(strings$string, "\\S+")
  starts <- unlist(lapply(gaps, function(x) x[, 1]))
  starts_len <- unlist(lapply(lengths(gaps)/2, seq, 1))
  dists <- lapply(seq(gaps), function(i) dist(c(gaps[[i]][, 1], nchar(strings$string[i]) + 2)) - 1)
  bits_dt <-  data.table(dist = unlist(dists), str_no = rep(strings$str_no, lengths(dists)), start = rep(starts, starts_len), key = "str_no")

  setkey(strings, str_no)
  for (len in unique(nchar(words))) {
    cat(len, "\n")
    words_right_length <- words_dt[nc == len]
    bits_right_length <- bits_dt[.(strings[is.na(result), str_no])][dist == len]
    bits_right_length[, matches := match(substr(strings[str_no, lower], start, start + dist - 1), words_right_length$lower)]
    matched <- bits_right_length[, .(first_match = na.omit(matches)[1]), by = str_no][!is.na(first_match)]
    if (nrow(matched) > 0) {
      matched[, word := words_right_length[first_match, word]]
      setkey(matched, str_no)
      strings[matched, result := word]
    }
  }

  strings[, `:=`(lower = NULL, str_no = NULL)]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @NickKennedy and sorry for the late reply. But there is a slight issue that I came across. The algorithm doesn't do an exact match. For eg, If the **String** is 'He lives in Yorkshire' and **Keyword** list contains York, it returns York as a **result** which it should not. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @red but in your example you give York as the result for He lives in Yorkshire. Do you only want whole words matched?

Comment: Sorry...I did not notice that edit. Yes, I want the exact whole words matched.

Comment: @red try the above. It's also much faster.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this is the most ideal solution, but it does work:

```
stringFrame <- data.frame(String = c("I love New York","Live in Los Angeles","He stays in Yorkshire","Condo in Lowell"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
 wordFrame   <- data.frame(Keywords = c("Ohio","Montreal","Los Vego","York","New York","Lowell"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 result <- stringFrame
 for (i in 1:dim(result)[1]){
  string = result[i,"String"]
  temp = ""
  for (word in wordFrame$Keywords){
    if (grepl(word,string,ignore.case=TRUE)){
      if (nchar(word) > nchar(temp)){
        result[i,"Result"] <- word
        temp <- word
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I saw in the title that you were looking for the longest word, so I updated the answer.  Now you will always get

```
 String               Result
 I love New York    New York
```

Comment: You can use `ignore.case` in `grepl` instead of "lowering" each word or string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution @Wannes. But, its still not doing the exact match. Eg. York is returned even when the keyword is Yorkshire. Is there a way around this? Also it would help if the result is a vector containing all matched Keywords like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stringdist` package, which implements the longest common substring method. The `amatch` function can be used to match 'words' to your strings:

```
strings <- data.frame(string=c("I love New York","Live in Los Angeles",
  "He stays in Yorkshire","Condo in Lowell"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
words   <-c("Ohio","Montreal","Los Vego","York",
  "New York","Lowell")

library(stringdist) 

strings$result = words[amatch(strings$string, words, method="lcs", maxDist=1E6)]
```

AS @NickK commented this matches `Lives in Los Angeles` to `Los Vego`. In order to filter these partial matches out you can do

```
# filter out partial matches
match <- nchar(strings$string) - nchar(strings$result)  ==
  stringdist(strings$result, strings$string, method="lcs")
strings$result[!match] <- NA
```

This solution seems to be slightly slower than that of @NickK. Using his example data set, the solution above takes 486 seconds on my system, while his takes 416 seconds.

Comment: This doesn't return the results the OP wanted - it matches `"Lives in Los Angeles"` to `"Los Vego"`.

Comment: @NickK You are right. I have added two lines of code that filter these partial matches out